# Launch method after Game Center view closes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, game-center

Is there any way to know when the user dismisses the Game Center view controller?

Scenario: User desires to view a previous score, so they tap, "View Scores," the Game Center view loads, they view their score, then they click "Done." Is there any way to launch a method when the "Done" is clicked.

I do not think that viewDidDissapear will work for this, because it is a remote view. What do you think?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the GKLeaderboardViewController's leaderboard-delegate to **self**.

```
leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
```

then use the method:

```
- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController {

}
```